# Pass data child->parent only when parent presses button

Tags: performance, mvvm, uwp, parent-child, observer-pattern

I have a UWP app using MVVM Toolkit. I have a parent ViewModel and a child UserControl.
Everyone says I should pass data from child to parent using Observer pattern. Which is good. MVVM Toolkit provides some classes and methods Send/Receive.

### Question

How do I pass data from child user control to parent? The child has 10 text boxes and the parent needs that data after clicking a button 'Create File'. I cannot use Observer Send method after each key press in a text box.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid>...
    <uc:MetadataUserControl>
    </uc:MetadataUserControl>

    <Button Content="Create final"></Button>
</Grid>
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```csharp
private MainPageModel _mainPageModel = null; // Business layer model
public MainPageModel MainPageModel
{
    get { return _mainPageModel; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _mainPageModel, value); }
}

void Receive() { .. } // Receive data from user controls
```

**MainPageModel.cs**

```csharp
    public MetadataModel {get; set;}
```

**MetadataViewModel.cs**

```csharp
private MetadataModel _metadataModel = null; // Business layer model
public MetadataModel MetadataModel
{
    get { return _metadataModel; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _metadataModel, value); }
}

void Send() {} // Notify parents subscribed to this user control
```

**MetadataUserControl.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <!-- First textbox -->
    <TextBlock Text="First textbox"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.MetadataModel.FirstText}"></TextBox>

    <!-- Second textbox -->
    <TextBlock Text="Second textbox"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.MetadataModel.SecondText}"></TextBox>
    ...
</Grid>
```

**SecondMainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid>...
    <uc:MetadataUserControl>
    </uc:MetadataUserControl>

    <Button Content="Create final"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So what is your real question? Be focus on the real problem you want to ask.

Comment: Create a dependency property in the usercontrol. Bind it to the a property in the ViewModel in the parent. When you click the final button, extract data from 10 textboxes and give the value to the dependency property. So the ViewModel will get the value

Comment: It seems this way the parent and child are coupled. If I have SecondMainPage which uses the user control. Do I run into problems? Edited question and added all the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to do it using Messenger's request feature. When the parent sends an event, the children replies with the object required.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
private void CreateFile()
{
    // Request data from children user controls
    var metadataRequested = WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send<MetadataRequestMessage>();
    
}
```

**MetadataViewModel.cs** constructor

```csharp
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MetadataViewModel, MetadataRequestMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    m.Reply(r.MetadataModel);
});

.. 
public class MetadataRequestMessage : RequestMessage<MetadataModel>
{
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and my suggestion...?

Comment: "in your Send() method in the child's view model" My answer has the function Send()  in the parent and you did not mention Reply() function, so I am thinking you are referring to a different method. 
The capability of Messenger to do data requests is life saving. Your answer also provides good alternatives in the usual Observer way. Where one class subscribes and the rest send messages. But in this way my child class has to Send after each TextBox key press in order for the parent to have latest updated Metadata state.

Comment: No. As I mentioned, you should call `Send` in the child view model when the button is clicked.

Comment: The button is in the parent class MainPage.xaml. Is there some way to press button in parent class and call Send() function in child?

Answer (score 0):

Call `WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new NotifyParentMessage(new YourInfoClass()));` in your `Send()` method in the child's view model and make sure that the `YourInfoClass` class contains all information that the parent view model needs about the child, i.e. the values of all properties that are bound to the textboxes in the view.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Question: Shouldn't it be a performance problem if I Send() data to parent after each keypress in textboxes?
Or should I change the approach and forget about Messenger and link DataContext from parent to child element
 <uc:MetadataUserControl DataContext="MainPageModel.MetadataModel"></uc..>

Comment: You should call `Send` when the button is clicked, not after each key stroke.

Comment: To answer your other question, yes, you might as well bind the textboxes directly to the parent view model if it needs the values sooner or later anyway.